# RadGrid InsertCommand event repeats on every page refresh

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm using MasterTableEditForm for inserting rows in RadGrid. In edit form I have a button with commandname = "PerformInsert" property, for inserting new row.

In C#, I'm using InsertCommand event for my custom insert logic. 
After this, my MasterTableEditForm is closing, but every time when I refresh page, InsertCommand is handling again with commandname = "PerformInsert" property and Insert operation is repeating.

So what can I do, to avoid multiple InsertCommand handling?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you must detach event after handling logic for Insert event, if that is not a problem you must seperate logic for refreshing your model from acion for your button, because method for the button should not be runnnig on refresh

Comment: I've tried event detaching, but unfortunately problem was not solved.